# Secure data ingestion in Apache Spark on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am planning to launch a Spark cluster on AWS EC2 instances using(https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/ec2-scripts.html). This is planned to be in a private subnet in a custom VPC.

With this background I see two options for secure data ingestion from the Internet:

1. Use S3 as the landing area and move data to Spark master node with a VPC S3 endpoint. There will be costs associated with POST/GET requests
2. Use a NAT instance in a separate public subnet and land the data directly in the master node of the spark cluster. There will be no costs apart from the extra EC2 NAT instance/NAT gateway.

Do you consider both options secure? If so, which one would you prefer?